# Scroll to top button is not hidden when using css display:none;

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following script for scroll to top function,

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });

**html**
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>

**css**
    .scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    left:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url('{{ 'icon_top.png' | asset_url }}') no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .scrollup {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i'm using this script the `display:none;` in my css (under `@media`) is not in use. i need it to hide the button in mobile devices.

The bottom script (with different css) is working fine, but i want to use the above for the fadeIn fadeOut use.

What i'm missing?

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(window.scrollY > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').css('bottom', -8);
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').css('bottom', -100);
    }
});
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: why are you using `#scrolltotop` with the top function? `.scrollup` is being used as the "button"

Answer (score 0):

Does that element have an ID of `#scrolltop` and also a class of `.scrollup`? for what you're doing it sounds like it would need both for jQuery to find it.

If the real goal is to hide this on mobile devices you may want to use a media query instead.

```
@media (max-width:699px) {
    #scrolltotop, .scrollup { display: none; }
}
```

This will hide that button on any web browser that is narrower than 700px.

*** --UPDATE-- ***

Since you're already going that route and it's not working you might just want to do a mobile browser detect to handle this.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('.scrollup').css({display:'none'});
}
```

You can find the full, expanded version of that test here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

With this approach you can hide this and any numnber of elements that you don't want to show up on the page when viewing it on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery .hide() instead/

```
$('.scrollup').hide();
```

Some ways to check for mobile besides what has been discussed in the other answers

1)

```
 if( useragent.search("iphone") )
    ; // iphone
else if( useragent.search("ipod") )
    ; // ipod
else if( useragent.search("android") )
    ; // android
```

2)

```
var isMobileDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i) != null 
    || screen.width <= 480;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with the following:

```
@media print { 
    .scrollup { 
        display: none; 
        bottom: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        width: 0px; 
        height: 0px; 
        visibility: hidden; 
    }
}
```